# iOS app got rejected just because of i have used Facebook login only for authentication purposes and no other login option

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store, facebook-login

My app is related with restaurants listing and liking (Only within the app not on Facebook) the restaurants. And facebook is the only way to get logged in into the app. But i have not used any facebook features into the app.

**I have got following reply from review team:**

`Also, we noticed that your app uses Facebook login for authentication purposes but does not include account-based features offered by that site, which does not comply with the App Store Review Guidelines.`

`In order to use Facebook for authentication, your app must include significant account-specific functionality from Facebook. For example, your app should include sufficient account-based features from Facebook other than pulling profile information or sharing on the user’s page.`

i am not using any special functionality of facebook in app but i wants to get app approve from review team. But i am unable to figure out what should be the best explanation for review team. 
And there is no way to integrate new app based login functionality at this time.

your help is appreciated.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions regarding app store approval are off-topic

Comment: @ Anbu.Karthik .. Question is nearly similar, but that solution doesn't work for me.

Comment: @Suraj -- facebook is authenticate purpose only , in manually create the login and signup page and access your app, the apple does not reject your app

Comment: If your app allowed users to search for restaurants and only required a Facebook login if they pressed the 'like' button it may be approved, but if the app is not functional without a Facebook login and 'like' is the only functionality offered then it is quite possible that your app cannot be approved as it does not offer sufficient functionality